# Setting constant buffer after UpdateSubresource creates error

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-11

I'm creating a constant buffer in DirectX 11 like this:

```
ID3D11Buffer* CreateConstantBuffer(uint32_t size)
{
    ID3D11Buffer* constantBuffer;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc{};
    cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    cbDesc.ByteWidth = static_cast<uint32_t>(size + (16 - (size % 16)));
    cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    cbDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    cbDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

    HRESULT result = device->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, nullptr, &constantBuffer);
    CheckDXError(result);

    devContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &constantBuffer);
    return constantBuffer;
}
```

Updating the constant buffer:

```
void UpdateConstantBuffer(ID3D11Buffer* constantBuffer, const void* data, uint32_t size)
{
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    HRESULT result = devContext->Map(constantBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    CheckDXError(result);
    memcpy((float*)mappedResource.pData, data, size);
    devContext->Unmap(constantBuffer, 0);

    devContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &constantBuffer);
}
```

`CheckDXError` just prints any DirectX errors to the console and breaks if there is any.

Creating and updating the buffer:

```
auto constantBuffer = CreateConstantBuffer(sizeof(glm::mat4));

// In update loop
UpdateConstantBuffer(constantBuffer, &cameraMatrix /* the view projection matrix */, sizeof(glm::mat4));
```

But in the debug output in visual studio, I am getting this error:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers: A Buffer trying to be bound as a Vertex Shader ConstantBuffer did not have the appropriate bind flag set at creation time to allow the Buffer to be bound as a ConstantBuffer. [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #246: VSSETCONSTANTBUFFERS_INVALIDBUFFER]
```

Comment: You have shown 2 places in your code where `VSSetConstantBuffers` is called. On which does the error occur exactly?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk the error occurs on the one in the update function.

Comment: Are you sure that the buffer you use in update loop was created using `D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER` flag? In `CreateConstantBuffer` the buffer is created correctly and `VSSetConstantBuffers` doesn't complain there, so this error shouldn't occur for the same buffer later. Maybe there is some intricate memory issue (eg due to stack corruption during array out-of-bounds access or the like) which manifests itself inside the update loop, which causes unexpected changes to the local variables. Try to test using `UpdateConstantBuffer` right after creating the buffer, does the error occur in this case?